# Kohana 3 - redirect to 404 page

Tags: php, kohana

After searching internet I haven't found answer to my question.
For example, in base complectation if you go to `http://yoursite/welcome/`  you'll see `hello world` but if you type http://yoursite/welc**om**/  you'll see `Fatal error: Uncaught HTTP_Exception_404 [ 404 ]: The requested URL welcom/index was not found on this server. ~ SYSPATH/classes/kohana/request/client/internal.php [ 94 ] thrown in`

From here, how can I redirect user to 404 page if he type wrong address?

Kohana 3.1.3.1

Comment: What exact kohana3 version do you use - 3.0, 3.1?

Answer (score 3):

Here is how we do it:

1. [Declare our own exception handler](https://github.com/kohana-world/kw-core/blob/master/init.php#L3) somewhere in bootstrap.php or module's init.php. Now all application exceptions will be sent to `Kw_Exception_Handler::handle()`.
2. [Exception handler](https://github.com/kohana-world/kw-core/blob/master/classes/kw/exception/handler.php#L19) analyses exception type (using `getCode()` method) and creates a new HMVC request with special [error controller](https://github.com/kohana-world/kw-core/blob/master/classes/controller/error.php), for example ('error/404').

Also you can add check for AJAX calls and return json structure with error text.

PS. [This userguide tutorial](http://kohanaframework.org/3.1/guide/kohana/tutorials/error-pages) may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work for you: [How to setup a custom 404 page for a Kohana v3 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463862/how-to-setup-a-custom-404-page-for-a-kohana-v3-app)

I think this is referring to Kohana 3, though.  I think you need to use `HTTP_Exception_???` and `execute()` is called in index.php by default (by `Request::factory()`, not `Request::instance()`.  I think you can work it out from there.