# How to load 404 custom page for Kohana3 dynamically?

Tags: php, kohana-3, custom-error-pages, kohana-3.2

I've used a solution from [how-to-setup-a-custom-404-page-for-a-kohana-v3-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4463862/how-to-setup-a-custom-404-page-for-a-kohana-v3-app), thanks to mdskinner. So, my working code is like:

```
Kohana_Exception::$error_view = 'kohana/404';//bootstrap.php

and the view file path is system/views/kohana/404.php
```

Unfortunately, the 404 page is a static page. But, I want to load the footer dynamically exactly as it is at any other page - using controller and view. Is that possible for 404 custom page?

Answer (score 1):

In your `index.php`, you put a try/catch block between your request execute and your echo, like this

```php
$request = Request::factory();

try
{
  $response = $request->execute();
}
catch (Exception $exc)
{
  if ($exc instanceof HTTP_Exception && $exc->getCode() === 404)
  {
     $response = Request::factory('your404route')->execute()->status(404);  
  } else {
    throw $exc;
  }
}

echo
  $response
  ->send_headers()
  ->body();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can easily. Please use official guide for 3.2 - http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/tutorials/error-pages or great blog post from Lysender - http://blog.lysender.com/2010/08/kohana-404-pages/ (this is actually for 3.1 version but the changes between 3.2 and 3.1 are not that big).

Comment: Shouldn't you at least paste the answer instead of linking to an external page? Refer to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers